# DataFrame update not saved to a file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm seeing this weird issue where updates made to a DataFrame are not being written to file. I know for a fact that there are rows which satisfy the condition and should get updated. Maybe I'm missing something very obvious and a fresh set of eyes will help.

```
prev_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True) # just for prior context in case it matters
df.loc[(df['TBL'].str.contains('abc')) & (df['DT'] == prev_date),'FLAG'] = 'Y' # can't see this update in the outfile csv file written
df.sort_values(by=['TBL']).to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

When I read the output file written above in console and repeat the same steps there, I can see the update happening. Any clue on what I'm missing?

Structure of `df`:

```
TBL     DT      FLAG
aab 2020-07-16    Y
abc 2020-07-15    N
abb 2020-07-15    N
```

Update 1: `df['DT'] == prev_date` strangely is not working

Update 2: `df['DT'].astype(str) == prev_date` fixed the issue but don't know why `str` casting is required when `DT` is of object type.

Comment: Per your update you are probably comparing a string to a date or two strings in different formats, etc. As such, I have deleted my answer. Nothing wrong with you `.loc` logic.

Comment: Does DT column is parses as Date or string? what is DT's column type?

Comment: DT column data type is object. I run `df.loc[(df['DT'] == prev_date),'FLAG'] = 'Y'` in Python console on the input dataframe and it works but not when I execute the program and check with a debugger